# Not allowed to load local resource with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have put in an upload form in my Laravel application, the file uploads and saves it but when I try to display it I get `joew:1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/socialNet/public/uploads/joew.png`

This is the root I put in the filesystems.php file

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('public/uploads'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

So the photo is being saved inside a folder called public inside the storage folder.

This is the function retrieving the file

```
 public function getUserAvatar()
    {
         if ($this->username) {
          $userAvatar = User::where('username', $this->username)->value('avatar');
            return "{$userAvatar}";
        }
        if (!$user) {
            abort(404);
        }

    }
```

and this is the format that it is saved in the database.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\socialNet\public\uploads\joew.png
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your browser is not allowed to directly load that file from your harddrive. In your view you are probably getting something like this:

`<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\socialNet\public\uploads\joew.png" />`

You need a URL for the browser to access this image. In your view you need something like:

`<img src="{{ asset('uploads/joew.png') }}" />`

The `asset()` function from Laravel creates a URL from the `public` folder and appends the param you give it. So this will create a URL like:
`http://localhost/public/uploads/joew.png`

Edit: The folder you specified (storage_path) is probably not readable for the browser at all. Change the uploads to `public_path('uploads')` and it will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks this finally makes sense, but where I am using the function to return it like this <img src="{{ asset($user->getUserAvatar()) }}" />

Comment: It's a bit hard without more of the code, but instead of `return "{$userAvatar}";` you might be able to use `return asset('uploads/' . $user->getUserAvatar())` if that method just returns the filename of the avatar. In the end, you need to give the browser a URL instead of a file path to the file.

Comment: I should state that using helpers like 'url()' and 'asset()' in your config files makes artisan completely useless as it malfunctions.