# Laravel 5.2 Not allowed to load local resource: from storage folder

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I am trying to preload images from the storage folder in the dropzone. This is what I have:

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: "suspect_images",
    data: { id: $('input[name=b_id]').val(), _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.images, function (key, value) {
            var file = {name: value.original, size: value.size};
            dropZone.options.addedfile.call(dropZone, file);
            dropZone.options.thumbnail.call(dropZone, file, value.path + value.server);
            dropZone.emit("complete", file);
            dropZone.files.push(file);
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {

    }
}, "json")
```

Controller

```
$images = Mugshots::select("AccusedID", "FileName", "OriginalFileName")->where("AccusedID", "=", $request->input('id'))->get();

$imageAnswer = [];

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $imageAnswer[] = [
        'original' => $image->OriginalFileName,
        'server' => $image->FileName,
        'size' => File::size(storage_path() . '/uploads/images/suspects/' . $request->input('id') . '/full_size/' . $image->FileName),
        'path' => storage_path() . '/uploads/images/suspects/' . $request->input('id') . '/full_size/'
    ];
}

return response()->json([
    'images' => $imageAnswer
]);
```

This returns

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/IMS/storage/uploads/images/suspects/2/full_size/file.jpg
```

Now this might probably work if my images are in the public folder. But for security reasons I have to store it in the storage folder. I am able to access the file through the browser when I paste the url but not in the javascript. I think it may be because of permissions. How could I load the files from the storage folder and display it on the dropzone?

**I am asking about loading it to the dropzone and not to the image tag.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not allowed to load local resource with Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415159/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-with-laravel)

Comment: @hassan I'm asking about dropzone not just loading it in the image tag.

Comment: it's the same issue i think, your browser is trying to load a resource from a hard drive, for a dropzone you may need to load your image from tmp directory for instance.

Comment: @hassan I'd love to know how I should do that.

Comment: sorry, i just woken up that the question about about dropzone B). however, i think this would be helpful, https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server

Answer (score 0):

Browser is not allowed to load file from your hard-drive. If you don't want to put your file in public folder here one option I got.

```
$path = storage_path('path/to/your/file.extension');
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$base64 = base64_encode($data);

$src = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . $base64;

return "<img src={$src} />";
```

The idea is get content of your file and encode to [base64](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) then you can  response to your view, Laravel may has API for this kind of process.

Comment: Will this work for dropzone as dropzone has a different method for getting the files?

Comment: @FriencyFernandez I'm not sure about dropzone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call or set a {symbolic link} that would reference your {image file} to your [storage] directory.
Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php

For instance:

```
$sUploadImage = $image->getFilename();
$sStoragePath = storage_path() . '/uploads/images/suspects/' . $request->input('id') . '/full_size/';
$sPublicPath = public_path(). '/uploads/images/suspects/' . $request->input('id') . '/full_size/';
if (is_dir($sPublicPath) !== true) {
    mkdir($sPublicPath, 0755, true); // This would create a new directory (e.g 'public/uploads/images/suspects/{id}/full_size/')
}

// If there's no symlink exists (e.g 'public/uploads/images/suspects/{id}/full_size/{filename.png}', create a new one
if (is_link($sPublicPath . '/' . $sUploadImage) !== true) {
    symlink($sStoragePath . '/' . $sUploadImage, $sPublicPath . '/' . $sUploadImage);
}
```

In this manner, You have a 'shortcut link' that would refer the images from the [storage] directory to the [public] directory.

Then replace your {size} and {path} key in your {$imageAnswer} array.

```
'size' => File::size($sPublicPath . '/' . $sUploadImage),
'path' => $sPublicPath . '/' . $sUploadImage
```

Then you can now use those {images} in the dropzone as what @hassan mentioned in the comments.

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: Would this not allow access of the files directly in other instances?

Comment: What kind of instances are you referring about? 
What output did you get when you use the call {dropzone} mockup handler? https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server

// Create the mock file:
var mockFile = { name: "Filename", size: 12345 };
// Call the default addedfile event handler
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
// And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
// (@eeya: The url will be: /uploads/images/suspects/{id}/full_size/{image_file_name.png}
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "/image/url");

Comment: Is using symbolic link not risky?

Comment: It may depend on how you've setup your web server's .htaccess (e.g Apache)

Reference: http://serverfault.com/questions/195570/htaccess-security/195575#195575

http://serverfault.com/questions/244592/followsymlinks-on-apache-why-is-it-a-security-risk

I'm still not quite used configure apache2. I only know the basics for this one.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: Do you know why it says Cannot create symlink?

Comment: What OS are you using (e.g Windows / Linux)?

Comment: I am using Windows. I am not sure if I have root privilege on this account.

Comment: Okay. Since you're using laravel 5.2, This reference might help: stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view/30192351

Comment: Thanks eeya! I'll continue digging :)

Comment: Well, I did not. I proceeded with loading the images in a somewhat file manager instead.