# Why won't this PHP code feed in to the link TAG href attribute? (local host, not using laravel)

Tags: php, html, css, xampp, localhost

Disclaimer: I haven't got a clue what I'm doing with PHP I'm just playing around with it.

I have my css file in a folder named CSS and then my header.php and footer.php in the main site folder. If i include the header.php in other directories I am just using:

```
<?php include('../header.php'); ?>
```

I know this isn't the way to do it however I don't know how to configure it probably (with a config.php file etc..) but my issue is, once the header's included in files in any directory of course it will look for the css/main.css file in that folder so I've tried doing the following:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/JAGS/css/main.css' ?>" />
```

When I use the php line in the body it displays the path

```
E:/xampp/htdocs/JAGS/css/main.css
```

but if I use it there in the link tag then doesn't work.

What seems to be my problem other than the fact I'm clueless with PHP. Is there something else I should be using? Is there something I need to do in my xampp config files?

**Edit:** By "doesn't work" I mean the styles are not being applied.
**Edit 2:** Inspecting shows the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="E:/xamppp/htdocs/JAGS/css/main.css">
```

I know there's an extra p on the end of xampp, this is actually what I have the folder named. Is it because it's not saying "localhost/JAGS/CSS/main.css"? If so what would be the reason for this?

**Edit 3:** Console shows error below:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/xamppp/htdocs/JAGS/css/main.css
```

**Edit 4:** Not using Laravel

Thank you

Comment: Instead of saying "doesn't work" you should tell us what it does actually do. 404 on the file? Styles not applied?

Comment: Sorry, yes the styles aren't applied.

Comment: But the file was fetched and came back with a 200 OK?

Comment: @csmckelvey Yep, it's showing "<link rel="stylesheet" href="E:/xamppp/htdocs/JAGS/css/main.css">" in dev tools.

Comment: And in the console, there are no errors shown? As in `E:/xamppp/htdocs/JAGS/css/main.css` is the correct path?

Comment: There is an error in the console I just looked after I posted this. I'm an idiot, i still don't know how to get around it but the error says "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/xamppp/htdocs/JAGS/css/main.css"

Comment: Just because it is showing in source does not mean it was actually fetched correctly - you need to check the network tab to see what the server response was when the browser actually requested that file from the server.

Comment: status: "blocked:other"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not allowed to load local resource with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415159/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-with-laravel)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using Laravel but I'll see if these can help, thanks a lot @IsaacAbramowitz

Comment: Why not just do <link rel="stylesheet" href="JAGS/css/main.css" />
Hard code the path to the syle sheet. You don't need to specify the part of the path before document root.

Comment: @IsaacAbramowitz
The issue has nothing to do with Laravel. The specific error is because apache is configured to not allow access outside of the htdocs folder.

Comment: Oh my bad, I was just referring to the error, not the fact that it was Laravel

Comment: Thanks all, yeah I'm just doing jags/css/main.css - I don't know why I wanted to do it the other way, just experimenting I guess, couldn't figure it out anyway so just doing normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you require the document root, you should just place a dot in front of it and set the base url in a meta tag.

```
<base href="yourdomain.com">   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./JAGS/css/main.css'/>
```

Comment: I'm just using href="JAGS/css/main.css" now anyway, just wanted to do it with PHP :P thanks for answering.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could accept my answer (click the checkmark in front of it).